# How to delete duplicate copies of the entries which I get and keep only one entry after getting the data from Elasticsearch Index

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I am using :

curl -XGET 'Elasticserach endpoint/index/_search' -d '
{"query": {"match_all": {} },
          "size": 1000}'

which gives me 1000 documents attached in with the index.

Now in these documents, there are several fields but I only want OrganizationName from it which also I am able to do.

Now after all these, I will get a 1000 entries of OrganizationName(different values) but the catch here is that there are some values which are repeated several times.

I want that only one entry of OrganizationName should be there and rest all duplicated entries should be deleted or should not come even if that can be done.

How can it be done as the answers given on google are not helping me in this.

Comment: So you want to remove duplicates from the result set from within elasticsearch, if yes see here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html

Comment: @CraigvanTonder I am getting this error on Jenkins:when I use what you have shared.     [root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [OrgName] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."
      }]

Answer (score 0):

You could try terms aggregation on OrganizationName field, it can also be used with some other metric aggregation like count, cardinality,...